# Snowpark table creation failing even query executed successfully

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a table from other table in snowpark using parameterized value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE table_merge(DB varchar,SCHEMA varchar,TARGET_TABLE varchar, SRC_TABLE varchar)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'table_merge'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matched

def table_merge(session,DB,SCHEMA,TARGET_TABLE, SRC_TABLE ):
  session.use_database(DB)
  session.use_schema(SCHEMA)
  session.sql(f"CREATE TABLE {DB}.{SCHEMA}.{TARGET_TABLE} LIKE {DB}.{SCHEMA}.{SRC_TABLE}")
  table_count = session.sql(f"SHOW TABLES LIKE {TARGET_TABLE}")
  return table_count.count()
$$;
```

The table is not creating and the result return 0. i even didn't see the table when i ran query alone

Any solution to this?

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in “import when_matached”. Also, your handler name doesn’t match the defined function. You probably should put error handling in your code, as well

Comment: Hi @NickW, It was a spell typo while mimixing the actual code.. i used the correct code, but its not working

Comment: Hi - so what about the handler issue?

Comment: Hi There is no handler issue .. rest of code is working .. only issue with the creating table using the session.sql

Comment: If I try and run your SP CREATE statement then it errors with syntax issues. You have multiple input parameters with the same name, you don't have semi-colons at the ends of lines and, while happy to be proved wrong, I don't believe it would work with the handler as defined - and there may be other issues

Comment: @NickW i updated the code for more clarity

Comment: Tried running your updated CREATE statement and it gave an error "100357 (P0000): Could not find handler in function TABLE_MERGE with handler reverse_str". Please stop posting non-functioning code - actually test your code and only update your question when you have working code that doesn't do what you expect. When I changed the function name to match the handler name it compiled without issue - as I told you in my first comment 20 wasted hours ago!

Comment: @NickW i updated the handler details

Comment: @NickW i got the solution using snowpark API.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea i got the answer finally for creating a permanent table using snowpark API without using session

```
source_table_df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("my_new_table")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source_table_df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("my_new_table")
```

This mode, `overwrite`, is used to replace the contents of an existing table with the new data. If the table does not exist, it will create a new table with the given name. If the table exists, it replaces all the data in the table with the new data.

It does not specify anywhere I can find that you must be the table owner, but that is how we are experiencing it.

Reference: https://medium.com/snowflake/snowpark-with-python-part-3-afef7071928d